# Scala: Specs2 and Mockito: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.internal.invocation.Invocation.isToString

Tags: scala, mockito, specs2

I am having trouble running my Scala unit test with Specs2 and Mockito.

```
val response = mock[Response]

"MyResource" should {
    "handle NOT_FOUND from another WS" in {
      response.status returns NOT_FOUND // Exception thrown here
      anotherWS.getDetails("101010", "101") returns Future.successful(response)
      .....
    }
```

**Exception:**

```
org.mockito.internal.invocation.Invocation.isToString(Lorg/mockito/invocation/InvocationOnMock;)Z
org.specs2.execute.Error$ThrowableException: NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.internal.invocation.Invocation.isToString(Lorg/mockito/invocation/InvocationOnMock;)Z
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.internal.invocation.Invocation.isToString(Lorg/mockito/invocation/InvocationOnMock;)Z
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.defaultanswers.ReturnsEmptyValues.answer(ReturnsEmptyValues.java:59)
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.defaultanswers.GloballyConfiguredAnswer.answer(GloballyConfiguredAnswer.java:24)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockHandler.handle(MockHandler.java:99)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MethodInterceptorFilter.intercept(MethodInterceptorFilter.java:47)
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating to mockito 1.9.5 (was using 1.8.5) fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Mockito does not support mocking variables. Is `status` a variable on the `response` object? If so, one solution would be to define a getStatus() method, and then mock that method.

Comment: Status is not a variable. It is a function. I have also tried mocking my own methods and it is throwing the same exception

Comment: Updating to mockito 1.9.5 (was using 1.8.5) fixed the issue.